# Learning SharePoint 2013 & SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to learn how to use SharePoint 2013 OOTB and with SharePoint designer 2013. Creating Sites adding web parts/app parts creating workflows with sharepoint designer etc

I have been searching and searching online especially about how to build custom workflows. But my findings are always very simple or not conveying much knowledge. Books just tell you how things work on their own, but never how to apply them in conjunction to other things. I also attended a course and the same thing happened. I know how to create a page add web parts linking lists etc. But I need to come to a situation where I have an idea and can reason about how to achieve the result in sharepoint.

Can anyone who has a good insight point me to some links or even books that are relavant to my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're a relative beginner when it comes to SharePoint workflows, but you understand what SharePoint is. Therefore I recommend these courses from Lynda.com:

[SharePoint Designer 2013 - Custom Workflows](http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-tutorials/SharePoint-Designer-2013-Custom-Workflows/144025-2.html) 
[SharePoint Designer 2013 - Creating Data Driven Sites](http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-Designer-tutorials/SharePoint-Designer-2013-Creating-Data-Driven-Sites/180862-2.html) 
[SharePoint Designer 2013 - Branding SharePoint Sites](http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-Designer-tutorials/SharePoint-Designer-2013-Branding-SharePoint-Sites/155976-2.html)

If you're looking for something a little more advanced, try this course from Pluralsight:

[SharePoint 2013 Workflow - Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint2013-workflow-fundamentals)

Both of them will require a subscription to the sites, but believe me when I tell you the subscription cost is well worth it. Much of what I have learned, from beginner to now, is from these two sources. Now, more so from Pluralsight, since my knowledge has progressed.